# Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_slider_language()

Tags: wordpress, ubuntu, redis

I'm attempting to move my wordpress sites over to Google Cloud, I've moved two successfully with revslider - the third had a bloated database and I needed to trim some fat to get it in.

I'm now getting the following error when trying to view a slide from any of the front-end pages.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_slider_language() on null in /var/www/rr/wp-content/plugins/revslider/includes/output.class.php:675 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/rr/wp-content/plugins/revslider/includes/output.class.php(634): RevSliderOutput->add_slider_base() #1 /var/www/rr/wp-content/plugins/revslider/revslider.php(96): RevSliderOutput->add_slider_to_stage('new_home', '', '', '', '') #2 /var/www/rr/wp-includes/shortcodes.php(343): rev_slider_shortcode(Array, '', 'rev_slider') #3 [internal function]: do_shortcode_tag(Array) #4 /var/www/rr/wp-includes/shortcodes.php(218): preg_replace_callback('/\\[(\\[?)(rev_sl...', 'do_shortcode_ta...', '[rev_slider sli...') #5 /var/www/rr/wp-content/plugins/js_composer/include/helpers/helpers.php(240): do_shortcode('[rev_slider sli...') #6 /var/www/rr/wp-content/plugins/js_composer/include/templates/shortcodes/vc_column.php(94): wpb_js_remove_wpautop('[rev_slider sli...') #7 /var/www/rr/wp-content/plugins/js_composer/include/classes/shortcodes/core/class-wpbakerys in /var/www/rr/wp-content/plugins/revslider/includes/output.class.php on line 675

There has been a critical error on your website.

Learn more about debugging in WordPress.
```

I've attempted the following steps to no avail.

1. Switched theme.
2. Disabled all plugins.
3. Deleted all slides and attempted with a freshly made slide.
4. Updated all plugins, including deleting Slider Revolution entirely and reinstalling the latest version.
5. I removed some language packs from the VM in an attempt to claw back some space and thought that might've been it - but reinstalling with `apt-get -y install "check-language-support -l en"` doesn't seem to have helped.
6. Updated to PHP 7.4.8

I'm using a Google Cloud VM with OpenLiteSpeed, and MySQL+Redis. I changed the only relevant option I could see in Slider Revolution Global Config from using `default` as the language to `en`. The slide works as expected in preview mode within the admin panel.

Comment: It's impossible to know what is going wrong without seeing your WP setup, but this is the bit that concerns me : "*I needed to trim some fat to get it in*"... does this mean you manually deleted content from the database? If so, then that's the most likely cause. The database is crucial to the operation of any system, and manually deleting content can cause unrecoverable errors.

Comment: I had 150MB of sliders so deleting some of them and rebuilding is what I meant, 

No idea what the original issue was but it wasn't the database. I ended up setting up a fresh install and manually installing the plugins/theme before migrating the database over and it's working fine now.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by what appears to be a bug in the Revolution Slider plugin, at least as of v6.2.21 (and it [doesn't appear to have been fixed](https://www.sliderrevolution.com/documentation/changelog/) since).  In `revslider/includes/output.class.php:678` it calls

```
$lang = $rs_wmpl->get_slider_language($this->slider);
```

but if the WPML plugin is not installed, then `$rs_wmpl` is null.

Until they fix it you can hack the plugin to check for null, e.g.,

```
    //set slider language
    if($this->get_preview_mode() == false && !empty($rs_wmpl)){
        $lang = $rs_wmpl->get_slider_language($this->slider);
        $this->change_language($lang);
    }
```

Edit: This bug doesn't reproduce under ordinary page loads, but does reproduce when loading the site under WP-CLI, e.g., via `wp profile`.  Suspect it has something to do with the way global variables are handled in that case.